# Android - Completely hiding the bar with clock, battery

Tags: android, status, android-immersive

It is possible to hide the bar with the clock completely ? I mean complete full screen. I tried to use the IMMERSIVE_STICKY flag with the `onWindowFocusChanged()` method but the bar pulls down when I touch the edge of the screen.

Best regard

Comment: Possibly your answer is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style of the activity on the application tag of the manifest

```
<application
  ...
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
  ...
</application>
```

You can also do it programmatically by setting the WindowManager flags to your activity at runtime (as Anas Mehar answered)

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
...
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

Comment: yes but the status bar slides down when I touch the edge of the screen. I want to remove it permanently